# Multiple WCF Service with boilerplate error handling

Tags: c#, wcf

I have several (12) WCF services which are structured like this:

I have inherited a very large 10-year-old project, I've introduced some inheritance so that I can have 1 echo method where I can control the timeout and not have duplicate code everywhere.

The `PostalAddressFinderServiceService` (Shittly named I appreciate) is the autogenerated WCF class locally, this `GetWebRequest` method is overridden in all the WVF service that I have - the AddressFinderService is a smaller service so I want to analyse that, all the other service follow the exact same pattern but I will omit them for brevity.

```
public class LocalAddressFinderServerService : PostalAddressFinderServiceService, IWrapAutoGenService
{
    /// <summary>
    ///     Get the web request
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    ///     In some cases the first call to the web service works just fine,
    ///     but if in the following few minutes no new call to the web service is made,
    ///     the next call would throw the exception shown above.
    ///     This problem could be solved by altering the generated proxy class;
    ///     in the GetWebRequest function the KeepAlive property must be set to false
    ///     see http://weblogs.asp.net/jan/archive/2004/01/28/63771.aspx
    /// </remarks>
    /// <param name="uri">The uri</param>
    /// <returns>The web request</returns>
    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri uri)
    {
        var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest) base.GetWebRequest(uri);
        webRequest.KeepAlive = false;
        if (Globals.CompressResponse == true)
        {
            webRequest.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
        }
        return webRequest;
    }
}
```

This local service is consumed by the generic wrapper that pulls in the abstract `ServiceWrapper` class.

```
/// <summary>
///     A class to represent the service for the address finder
/// </summary>
public class AddressServiceWrapper : ServiceWrapper<LocalAddressFinderServerService>
{
    /// <summary>
    ///     The single instance of the address service
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly AddressServiceWrapper Service = new AddressServiceWrapper();

    /// <summary>
    ///     Prevents a default instance of the <see cref="AddressServiceWrapper" /> class from being created
    /// </summary>
    private AddressServiceWrapper()
    {
    }

    protected override LocalAddressFinderServerService AppWebService
    {
        get
        {
            if (_webService == null)
            {
                _webService = base.AppWebService;

                _webService.findAddressCompleted += PAFFindAddressCompleted;
            }

            return _webService;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets the display name for the web service
    /// </summary>
    public override string DisplayName => "Address Finder Service";

    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets the service reference string this is used within
    ///     the <see cref="ServiceURLs" /> settings file
    /// </summary>
    public override string RefString => "Address_Finder";

    /// <summary>
    ///     The find address completed event
    /// </summary>
    public event findAddressCompletedEventHandler FindAddressCompleted;

    /// <summary>
    ///     Attempt an address search
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="request">The request parameters</param>
    /// <param name="user">The logged in user</param>
    public void BeginSearch(FindAddressRequest request, User user)
    {
        try
        {
            AppWebService.findAddressAsync(user.ToServiceType(), request.ToServiceType());
        }
        catch (SoapException ex)
        {
            throw new ServiceException(ToolKit.ErrorDescriptionFactory.CreateInstance(ex));
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            throw new ServiceException(ToolKit.ErrorDescriptionFactory.CreateInstance(ex));
        }
        catch (ApplicationException ex)
        {
            throw new ServiceException(ToolKit.ErrorDescriptionFactory.CreateInstance(ex));
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Format a single address into name value pairs
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="request">The format address request</param>
    /// <param name="user">The logged in user</param>
    /// <returns>The format address response</returns>
    public FormatAddressRes FormatAddress(FormatAddressReq request, ServiceClient.askPAF.User user)
    {
        try
        {
            return AppWebService.formatAddress(user, request);
        }
        catch (SoapException ex)
        {
            throw new ServiceException(ToolKit.ErrorDescriptionFactory.CreateInstance(ex));
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            throw new ServiceException(ToolKit.ErrorDescriptionFactory.CreateInstance(ex));
        }
        catch (ApplicationException ex)
        {
            throw new ServiceException(ToolKit.ErrorDescriptionFactory.CreateInstance(ex));
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Get a list of selection criteria and filters
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="user">The logged in user</param>
    /// <param name="findType">The name of the selection choices being populated</param>
    /// <returns>The selection criteria</returns>
    public FindResponse GetFind(User user, string findType)
    {
        try
        {
            return new FindResponse(AppWebService.getFind(user.ToServiceType(), findType));
        }
        catch (SoapException ex)
        {
            throw new ServiceException(ToolKit.ErrorDescriptionFactory.CreateInstance(ex));
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            throw new ServiceException(ToolKit.ErrorDescriptionFactory.CreateInstance(ex));
        }
        catch (ApplicationException ex)
        {
            throw new ServiceException(ToolKit.ErrorDescriptionFactory.CreateInstance(ex));
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Login to the postal address finder service
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="request">The login request</param>
    /// <returns>The login response</returns>
    public LoginResponse Login(LoginRequest request)
    {
       return new LoginResponse(CallServiceSafely(AppWebService.login, request.ToServiceType()));
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Handle the find address completed event
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The sender of the event</param>
    /// <param name="e">The event arguments</param>
    private void PAFFindAddressCompleted(object sender, findAddressCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!e.Cancelled && FindAddressCompleted != null)
        {
            FindAddressCompleted(sender, e);
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see there is a TON of duplicate try catch code. This makes the classes quite bloated and this is the smallest one. The largest one is north of 15,000 lines of repeated try, method pass through and catch. I've applied the refactoring to the Login method of the previous class to show the reduction in code.

This is the abstract, generic class I have inserted so I have somewhere to introduce common logic. I've put in the `CallServiceSafely` methods that take "Funcs" and "Actions".

```
public abstract class ServiceWrapper<S> : IService 
    where S : IWrapAutoGenService, new()
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The local web service
    /// </summary>
    protected static S _webService;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the reference to the web service
    /// </summary>
    protected virtual S AppWebService
    {
        get
        {
            if (_webService == null)
            {
                _webService = new S {Timeout = 100000};

                if (URL != null)
                {
                    _webService.Url = URL;
                }
            }
            return _webService;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the display name for the web service
    /// </summary>
    public abstract string DisplayName { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Send an echo request to the server to test
    /// the availability of the service
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="echo">The text to send</param>
    /// <returns>The text returned by the service</returns>
    public virtual string Echo(string echo)
    {
        var originalTimeOut = AppWebService.Timeout;

        AppWebService.Timeout = 5000;

        var result = CallServiceSafely(AppWebService.echo, echo);

        AppWebService.Timeout = originalTimeOut;

        return result;
    }

    protected void CallServiceSafely(Action serviceMethod)
    {
        try
        {
            serviceMethod.Invoke();
        }
        catch (SoapException ex)
        {
            throw new ServiceException(ToolKit.ErrorDescriptionFactory.CreateInstance(ex));
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            throw new ServiceException(ToolKit.ErrorDescriptionFactory.CreateInstance(ex));
        }
        catch (ApplicationException ex)
        {
            throw new ServiceException(ToolKit.ErrorDescriptionFactory.CreateInstance(ex));
        }
        catch (FaultException ex)
        {
            throw new ServiceException(CreateErrorDescriptionInstance(ex));
        }
    }

    protected void CallServiceSafely<T>(Action<T> serviceMethod,T firstParam)
    {
        try
        {
            serviceMethod.Invoke(firstParam);
        }
        catch (SoapException ex)
        {
            throw new ServiceException(ToolKit.ErrorDescriptionFactory.CreateInstance(ex));
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            throw new ServiceException(ToolKit.ErrorDescriptionFactory.CreateInstance(ex));
        }
        catch (ApplicationException ex)
        {
            throw new ServiceException(ToolKit.ErrorDescriptionFactory.CreateInstance(ex));
        }
        catch (FaultException ex)
        {
            throw new ServiceException(CreateErrorDescriptionInstance(ex));
        }
    }

    protected void CallServiceSafely<T, TU>(Action<T, TU> serviceMethod,T firstParam, TU secondParam)
    {
        try
        {
            serviceMethod.Invoke(firstParam, secondParam);
        }
        catch (SoapException ex)
        {
            throw new ServiceException(ToolKit.ErrorDescriptionFactory.CreateInstance(ex));
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            throw new ServiceException(ToolKit.ErrorDescriptionFactory.CreateInstance(ex));
        }
        catch (ApplicationException ex)
        {
            throw new ServiceException(ToolKit.ErrorDescriptionFactory.CreateInstance(ex));
        }
        catch (FaultException ex)
        {
            throw new ServiceException(CreateErrorDescriptionInstance(ex));
        }
    }

    protected void CallServiceSafely<T, TU, TV>(Action<T, TU, TV> serviceMethod,T firstParam, TU secondParam, TV thirdParam)
    {
        try
        {
            serviceMethod.Invoke(firstParam, secondParam, thirdParam);
        }
        catch (SoapException ex)
        {
            throw new ServiceException(ToolKit.ErrorDescriptionFactory.CreateInstance(ex));
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            throw new ServiceException(ToolKit.ErrorDescriptionFactory.CreateInstance(ex));
        }
        catch (ApplicationException ex)
        {
            throw new ServiceException(ToolKit.ErrorDescriptionFactory.CreateInstance(ex));
        }
        catch (FaultException ex)
        {
            throw new ServiceException(CreateErrorDescriptionInstance(ex));
        }
    }

    protected void CallServiceSafely<T, TU, TV, TX>(Action<T, TU, TV, TX> serviceMethod,T firstParam, TU secondParam, TV thirdParam, TX fourthParam)
    {
        try
        {
            serviceMethod.Invoke(firstParam, secondParam, thirdParam, fourthParam);
        }
        catch (SoapException ex)
        {
            throw new ServiceException(ToolKit.ErrorDescriptionFactory.CreateInstance(ex));
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            throw new ServiceException(ToolKit.ErrorDescriptionFactory.CreateInstance(ex));
        }
        catch (ApplicationException ex)
        {
            throw new ServiceException(ToolKit.ErrorDescriptionFactory.CreateInstance(ex));
        }
        catch (FaultException ex)
        {
            throw new ServiceException(CreateErrorDescriptionInstance(ex));
        }
    }


    protected TR CallServiceSafely<TU, TR>(Func<TU, TR> serviceMethod, TU firstParam)
    {
        try
        {
            return serviceMethod.Invoke(firstParam);
        }
        catch (SoapException ex)
        {
            throw new ServiceException(ToolKit.ErrorDescriptionFactory.CreateInstance(ex));
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            throw new ServiceException(ToolKit.ErrorDescriptionFactory.CreateInstance(ex));
        }
        catch (ApplicationException ex)
        {
            throw new ServiceException(ToolKit.ErrorDescriptionFactory.CreateInstance(ex));
        }
        catch (FaultException ex)
        {
            throw new ServiceException(CreateErrorDescriptionInstance(ex));
        }
    }

    protected TR CallServiceSafely<TU, TA, TR>(Func<TU, TA, TR> serviceMethod, TU firstParam, TA secondParam)
    {
        try
        {
            return serviceMethod.Invoke(firstParam, secondParam);
        }
        catch (SoapException ex)
        {
            throw new ServiceException(ToolKit.ErrorDescriptionFactory.CreateInstance(ex));
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            throw new ServiceException(ToolKit.ErrorDescriptionFactory.CreateInstance(ex));
        }
        catch (ApplicationException ex)
        {
            throw new ServiceException(ToolKit.ErrorDescriptionFactory.CreateInstance(ex));
        }
        catch (FaultException ex)
        {
            throw new ServiceException(CreateErrorDescriptionInstance(ex));
        }
    }

    protected TR CallServiceSafely<TU, TA, TV, TR>(Func<TU, TA, TV, TR> serviceMethod, TU firstParam, TA secondParam, TV thirdParam)
    {
        try
        {
            return serviceMethod.Invoke(firstParam, secondParam, thirdParam);
        }
        catch (SoapException ex)
        {
            throw new ServiceException(ToolKit.ErrorDescriptionFactory.CreateInstance(ex));
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            throw new ServiceException(ToolKit.ErrorDescriptionFactory.CreateInstance(ex));
        }
        catch (ApplicationException ex)
        {
            throw new ServiceException(ToolKit.ErrorDescriptionFactory.CreateInstance(ex));
        }
        catch (FaultException ex)
        {
            throw new ServiceException(CreateErrorDescriptionInstance(ex));
        }
    }

    protected TR CallServiceSafely<TU, TA, TV,TX, TR>(Func<TU, TA, TV, TX, TR> serviceMethod, TU firstParam, TA secondParam, TV thirdParam, TX fourthParam)
    {
        try
        {
            return serviceMethod.Invoke(firstParam, secondParam, thirdParam, fourthParam);
        }
        catch (SoapException ex)
        {
            throw new ServiceException(ToolKit.ErrorDescriptionFactory.CreateInstance(ex));
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            throw new ServiceException(ToolKit.ErrorDescriptionFactory.CreateInstance(ex));
        }
        catch (ApplicationException ex)
        {
            throw new ServiceException(ToolKit.ErrorDescriptionFactory.CreateInstance(ex));
        }
        catch (FaultException ex)
        {
            throw new ServiceException(CreateErrorDescriptionInstance(ex));
        }
    }

    protected TR CallServiceSafely<TU, TA, TV,TX,TY, TR>(Func<TU, TA, TV, TX, TY, TR> serviceMethod, TU firstParam, TA secondParam, TV thirdParam, TX fourthParam, TY fifthParam)
    {
        try
        {
            return serviceMethod.Invoke(firstParam, secondParam, thirdParam, fourthParam, fifthParam);
        }
        catch (SoapException ex)
        {
            throw new ServiceException(ToolKit.ErrorDescriptionFactory.CreateInstance(ex));
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            throw new ServiceException(ToolKit.ErrorDescriptionFactory.CreateInstance(ex));
        }
        catch (ApplicationException ex)
        {
            throw new ServiceException(ToolKit.ErrorDescriptionFactory.CreateInstance(ex));
        }
        catch (FaultException ex)
        {
            throw new ServiceException(CreateErrorDescriptionInstance(ex));
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Create an error description from the WCF FaultException
    /// It may need further fixed after more implementations of WCF as is only currently used for the document printing
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="ex"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static ErrorDescription CreateErrorDescriptionInstance(FaultException ex)
    {
        if (ex.Reason.ToString().IndexOf((char)255) != -1)
        {
            string[] elements = ex.Reason.ToString().Split((char)255);
            ErrorDescription errorDescription = new ErrorDescription(elements[3], elements[1], elements[2], elements[0]);
            return errorDescription;
        }
        string severity = ex.Reason.ToString();
        string reason = ex.Reason.ToString();
        string message = ex.Message;
        object details = ex.StackTrace;
        ErrorDescription errorDesc = new ErrorDescription(severity, reason, message, details);
        return errorDesc;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a value indicating whether the service is
    /// available
    /// </summary>
    public bool ServiceAvailable { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the url of the service
    /// </summary>
    public string URL { get; set; }

    public abstract string RefString { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Clear data cached in the service
    /// </summary>
    public virtual void ClearCachedData()
    {

    }
}

public interface IService
{
    string DisplayName { get; }

    bool ServiceAvailable { get; set; }

    string URL { get; set; }

    string RefString { get; } //Uid for the Iservice, used in Esprit as the name of the setting that contains the url for the service

    string Echo(string @string);

    //Used to clear the cached user on logoff
    //this is done within EspritServiceStateController for each module
    void ClearCachedData();
}
```

The `ServiceWrapper` class now contains many `CallServiceSafely` methods. Is there a way I can have one block of try catch code or will I have to maintain all the blocks as I have now?

Final interface for completeness.

```
/// <summary>
///     Provides access to autogenerated WSDL services that allow you to "Echo" them to check for their
///     prescence
/// </summary>
public interface IWrapAutoGenService
{
    int Timeout { get; set; }

    string Url { get; set; }

    //It needs to be lower case as that is what the wsdl presents to us.
    // ReSharper disable once InconsistentNaming
    string echo(string echo);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question right your main concern is how to refactor all the `CallServiceSafely(...)` methods, so you don't have to maintain a lot of repetitive code. A way to go could be to have an `ExecuteMethod()` method like:

```
private void ExecuteMethod(Action action)
{
  try
  {
    action();
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    switch (ex)
    {
      case FaultException fe:
        throw new ServiceException(CreateErrorDescriptionInstance(fe));
      // TODO: Other specialized exception cases
      default:
        throw new ServiceException(ToolKit.ErrorDescriptionFactory.CreateInstance(ex));
    }
  }
}
```

and then call it from the `CallServiceSafely` methods like:

```
protected void CallServiceSafely<T, TU, TV>(Action<T, TU, TV> serviceMethod, T firstParam, TU secondParam, TV thirdParam)
{
  ExecuteMethod(() => serviceMethod(firstParam, secondParam, thirdParam));
  //serviceMethod.Invoke(firstParam, secondParam, thirdParam);
}
```

---

You could also do:

```
private void ExecuteMethod(Action action)
{
  try
  {
    action();
  }
  catch (FaultException fe)
  {
    throw new ServiceException(CreateErrorDescriptionInstance(fe));
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    throw new ServiceException(ToolKit.ErrorDescriptionFactory.CreateInstance(ex));
  }
}
```

---

```
    private T ExecuteFunc<T>(Func<T> function)
    {
        try
        {
            return function();
        }
        catch (SoapException ex)
        {
            throw new ServiceException(ToolKit.ErrorDescriptionFactory.CreateInstance(ex));
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            throw new ServiceException(ToolKit.ErrorDescriptionFactory.CreateInstance(ex));
        }
        catch (ApplicationException ex)
        {
            throw new ServiceException(ToolKit.ErrorDescriptionFactory.CreateInstance(ex));
        }
        catch (FaultException ex)
        {
            throw new ServiceException(CreateErrorDescriptionInstance(ex));
        }
    }
```

Which is maybe more "catchy" correct.